# Python code to R

Tags: python, json, r, base64, decode

I need to replicate following Python code in R:

```
payloadObject = {
        'request':'/v1/balances',
        'nonce':str(1417217972400792), 
        'options':{}
}
payload_json = json.dumps(payloadObject)
payload = base64.b64encode(bytes(payload_json, "utf-8"))
```

and so far I have

```
require("RJSONIO")

payloadObject <- list(request = "/v1/balances", nonce = "1417217972400792", options = {})
payload_json <- toJSON(payloadObject)
```

Can you help with the last line payload = base64.b64encode(bytes(payload_json, "utf-8"))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RCurl` has `base64` that you can use for the last part. I also used `jsonlite` vs `RJSONIO` (latter is a more modern fork):

```
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)

payloadObject <- list(request = "/v1/balances", 
                      nonce = "1417217972400792", 
                      options = {})
payload_json <- toJSON(payloadObject)
payload <- base64(payload_json)
```